# Pass parameter to anonymous function multiple times, provide callback for when all complete

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to create a JS array of 1 or many functions, each with their own parameters (provided within a closure), then invoke of all of those functions, and have a callback for when all are called.

Based on the [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967261/js-pass-parameters-as-variables-to-an-anonymous-function-and-invoke-it-later), I can create 1 function with the parameters needed:

```
var f = (function(value) {
    return function(){myFunction(value);};
}(k));
```

I want to have several of these functions, invoke them all, and provide a callback after all are called.

**[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminsmith/TgYxn/)** that attempts to do this, and does not work the way I want (it never calls my 3 functions).

**[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminsmith/4cYwp/)**, using jQuery.Deferred objects (it calls my 3 functions too soon).

The way I would expect the consle.log() output to be is:

```
do something first
f1 done variable one
f2 done variable two
f3 done variable three
all functions have completed
callback has been called
```

What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT:** There will be an unknown number of functions to be called (set arbitrarily from throughout my application), which is why I am pushing them to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Deferred docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) under the constructor section:

> jQuery.Deferred can be passed an optional function, which is called just before the constructor returns and is passed the constructed deferred object as both the this object and as the first argument to the function.

That is, the functions run as soon as you pass them to the `Deferred` constructor.  So, one possible way to solve the issue is to

1. make `f1`, `f2`, `f3` regular functions, which accept the `dfd` parameter and resolve it
2. wrap them in `Deferred` only when you're ready to run them.

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbFeN/2/) produces your expected output.

```
var v1 = 'variable one';

// array of functions to be called
var functions = [];

function callFunctions(callback) {
    var deferreds = functions.map(function(x) {
        return $.Deferred(x);
    });
    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function(){
        console.log('all functions have completed');
        if( callback && typeof(callback)==='function' ) callback();
    });
}

var f1 = (function(value) {
    return function(dfd) {
        console.log('f1 done',value);
        dfd.resolve();
    }
})(v1);

// this should be the first thing logged
console.log('do something');

functions.push(f1);

callFunctions(function() {
    console.log('callback has been called');
});​
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have an unknown number of functions however, so I need to put them in an array. Is there a way to adapt your method to accommodate this?

Comment: @BenjaminSmith I'm still pushing them to an array... I just removed #2 and #3 in what I posted here, for conciseness -- but all 3 are in the linked Fiddle.  Or am I missing something?  http://jsfiddle.net/qbFeN/2/

Comment: I just updated the original post - I will be push to this array at random points throughout the application, so I cannot push all functions as deferred at once unfortunately. Based on your fiddle, I may be adding to that array before the 'do something' log.

Comment: @BenjaminSmith that should be an easy fix -- just have the `callFunctions` function wrap each one in $.Deferred.  See updated Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qbFeN/3/

Comment: this 100% answers my question, but I wonder how this could be accomplished with the Deferred objets, or without jQuery at all...

Comment: @BenjaminSmith I assume some of the functions involve asynchronous calls and/or Ajax calls, right?  If so, then writing your own version in Javascript would have to involve something similar to `deferred.resolve()`, which each function would use to indicate when it's done.

Comment: No ajax in these functions right now - although I cannot guarantee that they're won't be in the future. Thank you.